# Why are the wings of most passenger jets on the bottom?

Tags: aerodynamics, commercial-aviation, airliner

I have always wondered why most manufacturers put the wings on the bottom of commercial jets. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hm, while that _should_ be a duplicate, the answers don't really address jets.

Comment: @JanHudec I think the only thing to add for transport jets is "and if you have an uncontained engine failure the bits of the engine will hit the wing instead of the passengers" -- or are there other characteristics you think are worth discussing separately?

Comment: Another related question: [Why do (almost) all military transports have high wings and civilian transports low wings?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/6319/69)

Comment: Another related question, with more answers: [Why is there really only one basic design for passenger airplanes?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8649/524)

Comment: I couldn't find any similar questions. Sorry.

Comment: low wings with underwing-mounted engines are easier to service - routine oil refill, filter inspections, leak inspection etc.