# What materials are used to build a military runway?

Tags: runways

What type of matrix should be used on a military runway used by C130 aircraft?

Comment: Asphalt, concrete, dirt, sand, snow, ice... C-130 is pretty versatile.

Comment: Same as the one you use for civilian runway. Military does not change the physics.

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19313/how-heavy-is-too-heavy-to-land-on-a-grass-strip/19335#19335

Comment: @vasin1987 Military aircraft are more commonly designed to deal with less-improved runways than civilian aircraft, especially in the case of military transport aircraft, which are frequently designed to be able to land on and take off from makeshift grass strips in the middle of a war zone or ice fields in Greenland or Antarctica.

Answer (score 3):

I believe C-130 was designed to be operated from unprepared runways for takeoffs and landings. One of the reasons for India to buy it and deploy it to forward operating base.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Dirt runways can be prepared through dust control by water.

Diego Garcia has been at least since the seventies had the coral reefs mined for aggregate.

Keep in mind that the matrix doesn't have to be high quality, it just has to last until the anticipated end of the war without excessive maintenance costs.